# How do I change the root JSON array element name in Robospice/Jackson?

Tags: android, jackson, robospice

I have this Request class that I am using in [Robospice](https://github.com/octo-online/robospice) and the [Google HTTP Java client](https://code.google.com/p/google-http-java-client/):

```
public class MyRequest {
    @Key
    private List<String> Items;
 //.....
}
```

Which I use:

```
MyRequest myRequest = new MyRequest();
myRequest.setItems(data);

this.postMyRequest = new PostMyRequest(myRequest);
getSpiceManager().execute(postMyRequest, new PostMyRequestListener());
```

and

```
JsonHttpContent jsonHttpContent = new JsonHttpContent(new JacksonFactory(), this.myRequest);

HttpRequest httpRequest = getHttpRequestFactory()
            .buildPostRequest(new GenericUrl(this.baseUrl), jsonHttpContent);
httpRequest.setParser(new JacksonFactory().createJsonObjectParser());

Response response = httpRequest.execute().parseAs(getResultType());
```

How to I change the root array name (from "Items") to somethings else?
I have tried `@JsonProperty("Foo")` but that didn't do anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, figured it out.

I extended my class from an `ArrayList` instead.

```
public class MyRequest extends ArrayList<String> {
 //.....
}
```

That made the root name blank/empty (Which is what I wanted anyway)

Comment: Yes you have to create a list class, that's the only way a container with generics can be truly represented as a type. A common practice is to define this class as a static inner class of the pojo class it contains, in one line. static class PojoList extends ArrayList<Pojo> {}